# laravel paginator is not working with LIKE in where clause

Tags: laravel, paginator

laravel paginator is not working with LIKE in where clause

laravel/framework version: v5.6.33

controller

```
$search_qs = $request->input('search');

$query = Article::where("status", 2);
$query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_qs . '%');
$articles = $query->paginate(3);
```

view

```
{{ $articles->links() }}
```

database queries

```
select * from `articles` where `status` = '2' and `title` LIKE '%txt2search%' limit 3 offset 0
```

!!! OK !!!

but, when I click on page 2 in the paginator

```
select * from `articles` where `status` = '2' and `title` LIKE '%%' limit 3 offset 3
```

Bindings

```
0. 2            (`status` = ?)

1. %%           (`title` LIKE ?)
```

values should be stored in session, or flash_session ?? but LIKE value is not retrieved

Comment: Where is the actual search term coming from? Is it an URL parameter?

Comment: yes from url parameter, sent  get from a search input texbox,

Comment: the same problem does not occur with a static text, for hours I bang my head, tks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to [append](https://laravel.com/docs/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) custom values like this to the pagination links:

```php
$articles = $query->paginate(3)->appends($request->only('search_qs'));
```